# Error in temp[requiredperson, ] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

[doubt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfji8.jpg)

```
for(i in 1:rowcount){    
   t = sum(temp[i,])     
   if(t>0){    
     rowmean = mean(temp[i,])    
     rowsd     = sd(temp[i,])*sqrt(colcount-1)    
     temp[i,] = (temp[i,]-rowmean)/rowsd    
   }    
 }    
 requiredperson =4661 #Obama    
 dotproducts = numeric(rowcount)     
 for( i in 1:rowcount){     
   dotproducts[i] =  sum(temp[requiredperson,]*temp[i,])    
 }
```

> Error in temp[requiredperson, ] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Please explain in few lines with example, what you are trying to achieve here, It would be helpful to others, and  you will get the desired help.

Comment: I have attached image file. So it would be helpful. I am practicing Text Analytics in R. Working around with DocumentTermMatrix in R.

Comment: You are selecting a row from `temp` that is bigger than `temp` I think. E.g. - selecting row 4 from a 3 row matrix - `matrix(1:3)[4,]` . That will give you the same error. Check the value of `requiredperson` and how many rows are in `temp`. This is all guessing though given the limited information available.

Comment: Yes, I found my error. Thanks thelatemail for finding out my error. Thank you very much.